# Dynamic Header in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to dynamically change the value of

```
[Header()]
```

in the inspector to show the location in the asset folder of one of the serializable objects.

Is that possible or any other good way to do that?

Ps. It is a scriptable object and has also its own custom editor.

Comment: Only with a custom editor script. Afaik the parameter for Header has to be compile time constant

Comment: @derHugo It has its own custom editor already but I couldn't figure out how to do that. Can you help me out please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a Custom Editor script using [`AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath.html) and a [`EditorGUILayout.LabelField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.LabelField.html) with [`EditorStyles.boldLabel`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorStyles-boldLabel.html) like e.g.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private ExampleScriptableObject example;
}
```

and then

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(Example))]
public class ExampleEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty example;

    // initialize the Inspector
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        example = serializedObject.FindProperty("example");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // fetch current values into the serialized properties
        serializedObject.Update();

        // if an object is referenced draw the path
        if (example.objectReferenceValue)
        {
            var path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(example.objectReferenceValue);
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField(path, EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        }

        // the usual reference field
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(example);

        // write back modified properties
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I did somethink like below and It worked perfect.



`public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
        serializedObject.Update();
        var obj = serializedObject.GetIterator();

if(obj.name == "Sudoku_Soru_Image")
                    {
                        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath( obj.objectReferenceValue ), MessageType.Info);
                    }

}`